# io socket is throwing error for App Transport Security in swift

Tags: ios, swift, socket.io, info.plist

I am trying to connect socket with the help of SocketIO but it's throwing error as **ERROR SocketEngine: The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection.** even I have defined the transport security in my info.plist file.

info.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_PACKAGE_TYPE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
</dict>
</plist>

controller code

//
//  ViewController.swift
//  socketioDemo
//
//  Created by developer on 9/12/21.
//

import UIKit
import SocketIO
final class Service: ObservableObject {
    private var manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: "ws://localhost:3000")!, config: [.log(true), .compress])
    var messages = [String]()
    init() {
        let socket = manager.defaultSocket
        socket.on(clientEvent: .connect, callback: { (data, ack) in
            print("connected to wss")
            socket.emit("Node js server port", "Hi Node Js Server")
        })
        socket.on("iOS client port") { [weak self] (data, ack) in
            if let data = data[0] as? [String: String], let rawMessage = data["msg"] {
                self?.messages.append(rawMessage)
            }
            
        }
        
        socket.connect()
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var service = Service()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
    

}
```

Comment: since this is a local network, maybe you also need to include in info.plist: <key>NSLocalNetworkUsageDescription</key> <string>${PRODUCT_NAME} uses the local network to do something</string> Also try "wss://localhost:3000" anyway, just to see if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

check the URL (socketURL)
make suer in web have ssl certifcat

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).